# download audio file from textreader.surge.sh with curl

Tags: curl

I'm trying to send a curl request to this website: https://textreader.surge.sh/ . I want to send text and have the server give me an audio file of that text as it is a text-to-speech program.

Does anyone know how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

first make a HTTP GET request to https://textreader.surge.sh/ , then do a HTTP OPTIONS request to `https://us-central1-sunlit-context-217400.cloudfunctions.net/streamlabs-tts` with an empty body and the http headers `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type` and 
`Origin: https://textreader.surge.sh` and verify that the response is literally `ok` ( [image] ) then do a HTTP POST request to `https://us-central1-sunlit-context-217400.cloudfunctions.net/streamlabs-tts` with the headers `Referer: https://textreader.surge.sh/` and `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` and `Origin: https://textreader.surge.sh` and have the POST body contain the data `"text":"<the text you wish spoken here>","voice":"Brian"}` encoded in JSON, the response looks like

```
{
    "success": true,
    "speak_url": "https://polly.streamlabs.com/v1/speech?OutputFormat=ogg_vorbis&Text=penis&VoiceId=Brian&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIHKNQTJ7BGLEFVZA/20190218/us-west-2/polly/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190218T112454Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=07652663d5024414ae4b4087fa39f9eaa8b912cc04dc7a5d7abecdaed5585396"
}
```

now simply issue a HTTP GET request to the "speaker url" with the HTTP headers `Referer: https://textreader.surge.sh/` and `Origin: https://textreader.surge.sh`, and voila, the response is your audio in ogg/vorbis format (which is basically like a non-proprietary, patent-and-royalty-free version of MP3)

- surprisingly, this website does not use cookies at all.

with PHP/[hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php) it would look like

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl('', true);
$hc->exec('https://textreader.surge.sh');
$response = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'OPTIONS',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type',
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://us-central1-sunlit-context-217400.cloudfunctions.net/streamlabs-tts',
))->exec()->getStdOut();
if (trim($response) !== "ok") {
    throw new \LogicException("unexpected response from https://us-central1-sunlit-context-217400.cloudfunctions.net/streamlabs-tts: {$response}");
}
$json = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://us-central1-sunlit-context-217400.cloudfunctions.net/streamlabs-tts',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => null,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'text' => 'the text you wish spoken here',
        'voice' => 'Brian'
    )),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Referer: https://textreader.surge.sh/',
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Origin: https://textreader.surge.sh'
    )
))->exec()->getStdOut();
//var_dump($json);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$ogg_vorbis_location = $data['speak_url'];
$ogg_vorbis_binary = $hc->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1)->exec($ogg_vorbis_location)->getStdOut();
file_put_contents("voice.ogg",$ogg_vorbis_binary);
echo "audio saved to voice.ogg.\n";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. On the last step I get a {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} . Do you know why?

Comment: @PetkoStoykov yes. since i wrote this post, they updated the webpage, it now requires to you fetch a cookie session prior to sending POST request to fetch the audio file. you can get the required cookie session at `https://textreader.surge.sh` , and my example code already does does on line 5.. not sure why i originally wrote line 5, it wasn't required back then, but it is required now. (and as a result, my sample code never broke, apparently)